# Three coupled non-linear differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear

I have a system of three coupled nonlinear differential equations to solve:

$$\dfrac{d}{ds}\left( \frac{r(s)^2 \theta '(s)}{f(r(s))}\right)=\dfrac{K^2\cot (\theta (s))}{\frac{r(s)^2 \sin ^2(\theta (s))}{f(r(s))}}$$

$$\dfrac{r'(s)^2}{f(r(s))}+r(s)^2 \theta '(s)^2=C^2 \left(f(r(s))-\dfrac{f(r(s))^2}{F^2}\right)-\dfrac{K^2}{\dfrac{r(s)^2 \sin^2(\theta (s))}{f(r(s))^2}}$$

$$\phi'(s)=\dfrac{K}{\dfrac{r(s)^2 \sin ^2(\theta (s))}{f(r(s))}}$$

where $K,\,F$ and $C$ are known positive parameters, and the function $f(r(s))$ is given by

$$f(r(s))=1-\frac{u}{r(s)}-A(3-2 p)\times \times_2F_1\left(\dfrac{1}{2(1-p)},-\dfrac{1}{1-p},1+\frac{1}{2(1-p)};\left(\dfrac{r(s)}{r_{c}}\right)^{2(1-p)}\right),$$

where $u,\;A,\;p,$ and $r_{c}$ are also known parameters, and $_2F_1$ is the Hypergeometric function.

I would like to solve the above system of non-linear differential equations given random initial conditions on $r(s),\;\theta(s),\;\phi(s)$ and fixing any value for the parameters $K,\,F,\;C$, $u,\;A,\;p,,\;r_{c}.$

The Mathematica code I used is

```
ORBITS[t_?NumericQ, t0_?NumericQ]:=Evaluate[{r[t] Cos[φ[t]] Sin[θ[t]], 
 r[t] Sin[φ[t]] Sin[θ[t]], r[t] Cos[θ[t]]}] /.
   NDSolve[{D[r[s]^2/f[r[s]] θ'[s], s] == K^2/(r[s]^2/f[r[s]])*Cot[θ[s]]/Sin[θ[s]]^2, 
     1/f[r[s]] (r'[s])^2 + r[s]^2 (θ'[s])^2 == C^2 (f[r[s]] - f[r[s]]^2/F^2) - K^2/(r[s]^2/f[r[s]]^2 Sin[θ[s]]^2),
     φ'[s] == K/(r[s]^2/f[r[s]] Sin[θ[s]]^2), 
     r[0.] ==2., θ[0.] == π, θ'[0.] == 1., φ[0.] == 0.},
     {r[s], θ[s], φ[s]}, {s, 0., t0}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
     Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}];
```

Whenever I try to use `NDSolve` I get the error message

```
NDSolve::ntdv: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. Consider using the option Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}.
```

So I use the suggested method `Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}` 
but instead it gives me another error

```
`NDSolve::mconly: For the method IDA, only machine real code is available. Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions.`
```

Then I changed for `Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Solve"}` 
and it runs without errors, but instead, to obtain a numerical value of any of the functions $r(s),\;\theta(s),\;\phi(s)$ at some point, let's say $s=0.5$ it takes forever.

Could someone please help me/suggest me how to improve `NDSolve` in order to solve numerically the above equations in a reliable time? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Could you please also post the code you're inputting to `NDSolve`? Retyping the differential equations may very well omit or introduce errors that may or may not be present in your code, which wouldn't be very helpful.

Comment: thanks dear @eyorble , I added the code

Comment: There are still undefined functions, like f and ERG. You should insert codes for them too.

Comment: ah, sorry dear @Himalaya, ERG is E, I already corrected

Comment: Don't use `E`, it well evaluate to `Exp[1]`.

Comment: If I haven't made any mistakes translating this back to MMA input then this `u=2;capA=3;p=4;rc=5;capK=6;capF=7;capC=8;p=9;t0=3/2;
f[q_]:=1-u/q-capA(3-2p)Hypergeometric2F1[1/(2(1-p)), -1/(1-p), 1+1/(2(1-p)), (q/rc)^(2(1-p))];
NDSolve[{D[r[s]^2*θ'[s]/f[r[s]],s] == capK^2*Cot[θ[s]]/(r[s]^2*Sin[θ[s]]^2/f[r[s]]),
r'[s]^2/f[r[s]] + r[s]^2*θ'[s]^2 == capC^2*(f[r[s]] - f[r[s]]^2/capF^2) - capK^2/(r[s]^2*Sin[θ[s]]^2/f[r[s]]^2), φ'[s] == capK/(r[s]^2*Sin[θ[s]]^2/f[r[s]]), r[0]==2, θ[0]==π, θ'[0]==1, φ[0]==0}, {r[s], θ[s], φ[s]}, {s, 0, t0}]` seems it just can't get r[s] and r'[s] out of your 2F1.

Comment: that's what I thought, as one of the errors with other methods is that one cannot get $r'(s)$ nor $\theta'(r)$ as a function of $r(s)$ and $\theta(r)$. But there should be a numerical method to solve differential equations.

Comment: That's fine except for the fact that you are putting the unknown function r[s] into HyperGeometric2F1 function and expecting somehow to be able to evaluate that HyperGeometric2F1 to something where you can potentially separate r[s], r'[s] and θ[s], which simply might not be possible to do. Look at the definition of HyperGeometric2F1 hidden under the Details tab in http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1.html and try to decide how the result of that can be separated. I'm only guessing but the fourth argument to that may be the issue. Do I have all of that exactly correct?

Comment: So, you mean that Mathematica can't solve certain types of differential equations numerically?

Comment: All this is guesswork, but I was more leaning in the direction that MMA, and maybe nobody in the world, could get variables (actually functions in your case) out of infinite sums of powers of those variables. Infinite sums can end up being almost anything.